# How to change start-, follow- and no-follow-URLs for StormCrawler on the fly

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I am pretty new to StormCrawler, doing my first implementation of a web-crawler and I am very happy with the product so far!

I am using StormCrawler v1.5.1 with Elastic 5.5.1 and setup my topology based on the provided "ESCrawlTopology.java".

I would like to be able to change the start-URLs (seeds) and follow-/no-follow-URLs while the topology is running. What I got so far is a redis-DB which holds this configuration and a URL-Filter which uses the redis to read its follow- no-follow-patterns from. 
Also I implemented a start-url spout which reads from the redis, detects changes and publishes newly found start-urls via the status-updater to elastic. 
So far this setup works great.

For the follow-/no-follow rules I also implemented a spout which detects changes and removes all no-longer matching URLs from the "index"- and "status"-Index in Elastic using the "DeleteByQuery"-Elastic-action. I am not using the Status-Updater or DeletionBolt for this.

Even though this works, it does not feel right and I do see potential issues. First of all I cannot use the caching of the status-updater because the deletion is not done via this component and thus the cache does not get updated, preventing the status updater to add URLs which were once added, removed and added again. Secondly when one or more URLs are being fetched or parsed while they are excluded and removed from the "status" and "index" I am unsure about the outcome. I expect the URLs in process being indexed despite them being excluded before.

I also experimented with a setup where I sent all excluded URLs to the status-updater with the ERROR status. In combination with the DeletionBolt this results in the URLs being taken out of the "index"-index. This seems like a cleaner solution - however URLs which are excluded once can never be re-indexed ever again, because they reside in the "status"-index as "ERROR".

The best solution in my eyes would be:

1. mark the excluded URLs in the "status"-index using the status "REMOVED" (not available at the moment)
2. make all components (fetcher, parser...) aware of the "REMOVED" status to discard an excluded URL currently in processing
3. implement a cleanup process which sends all "REMOVED" URLs to the DeletionBolt and also removes this URL from the "status" upon acking

Currently I do not see a way to implement this without major adjustments to the core-components of StormCrawler since there is currently no such Status as "REMOVED".

What are your thoughts on this problem and what could be a possible solution?

Comment: Hi Tobias. Glad to hear you like StormCrawler and thanks for this interesting question. I'll reply properly when I am back from holiday in 10 days but in the meantime could you give me a bit more context: what are you crawling for and why do you need to remove seeds and add them back again?

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for answering besides your holiday! I have been working with the Google Search Appliance (GSA) for the past 7 years. The GSA has a neat concept where it keeps a single Index for all the URLs included. The index can then be segmented into sub-indices (called collections) based on URL patterns. The cool thing is that the crawling for the index is continuously running (just like the StormCrawler) and can be managed by three main settings: start-URLs, follow-Patterns and no-follow-Patterns. These settings can be changed at any given moment without the need to restart the crawler.

Comment: This concept worked very well since you were able to discover your content, find things you did not want in your index and were able to exclude them very easily and quickly. I am trying to build a solution which handles the indexing in the same way. Have a great vacation!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new REMOVED status would not necessarily be very straightforward, as you pointed out.

Instead of removing URLs in ES, what about adding a custom boolean field to the search index e.g. *active* with a default value of true so that if things are added back later on, all you'd have to do is to switch the value in the index. Obivously you'd have to scan that index to change the values but that would be done outside SC.

From the status index point of view, things would be kept even if they are deactivated, it's just that you'd have a real-time URL filter + possibly extend the ES indexing code so that it checks the patterns every so often and generates the correct value for the *active* field.

Does that make sense?